# Earth's moon shortens human lifespan

Tags: story-identification, novel, moon

I checked out this novel, probably young adult, from my hometown library sometime in the late 80s or early 90s.

The plot follows a human looking race of aliens that come to earth to investigate why our race "only" lives 70-80 years (the aliens have a lifespan of several centuries, and have to use personal journals to remember the details of their lives).

Someone decides the moon is involved in determining our lifespan since no other humanoid race lives on a planet with such a massive satellite so close.  The climax involves one of the aliens going crazy and deciding to destroy the moon to "save the humans".  Another member of the research team thinks destroying the moon will horribly damage the earth and also envies humans for savoring our short lives so s/he attempts to stop the first.

Comment: Um, my question (with an accepted answer) from three years ago was marked a duplicate of a question posted end of last month?  That seems backwards to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to USENET: Ceres Solution, by Bob Shaw

From a review at https://sfbook.com/the-ceres-solution.htm :

> If you are an old hand a science fiction, there's a good chance that you've heard the theory or read a story that put forward the theory, that our large moon is the reason for development of intelligent life on Earth. If you've read any number of essays by Asimov, larger than two, chances are you have heard about it. In The Ceres Solution Shaw puts forward the opposite possibility, namely that the moon is the reason why earth is in such a bad state.

Comment: Could you indicate why this story fits the description of the OP, for example using quotes?